# Cloning Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu dd

Tags: windows-8, usb-drive, dd, clone, cloning

Will there be any problem/caveat when I have a hda disk with Windows 8.1 system and with a bootable flash disk I enter under Ubuntu system this command:

```
dd if=/dev/hda of=/dev/hdb bs=1M
```

Comment: Maybe look into using [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) for disk cloning.  It's in the repositories.  `sudo apt install clonezilla`

Comment: I would prefer to see an answer to my original question. I do not wish to install anything to my bootable flash disk.

Comment: As long as the drives that you are cloning match what you have there it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I just wondered whether I should actually write dd if=/dev/hda1 of=/dev/hdb1 bs=1M instead of dd if=/dev/hda of=/dev/hdb bs=1M?

Comment: That's partition cloning when you add the #'s and not disk cloning.  Disk cloning copies everything including the partition tables and boot sectors, etc.

Comment: @Terrance And what about formating the SSD disk if it is brand new? How do I do that?

Comment: dd should take care of that as it does a bit copy.  No format needed.

Comment: IF Windows 8 and UEFI boot, only use dd on entire drive. The newer gpt partitioning has GUID info in partition table, partition & backup partition table at end of drive. And if not same size drive, you will have to use gdisk or sgdisk to move back up partition table to end of drive.

Comment: [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org) is both safer and faster: Safer because it has checkpoints, that help you make sure that you will write to the correct drive. Faster because it is smart enough to only clone the partition table, and the used blocks in the file systems (in other words, it skips free blocks, that contain no file data). Futhermore, I suggest that you download a Clonezilla iso file, make a USB boot drive, and boot from it, so there is no need to install anything to your bootable Ubuntu flash disk.

Comment: I've succesfully cloned my HDD. However it has 4TB from which I can use only 2TB. The remaining 1.36TB is UNALLOCATED and not visible by the Win 8.1. How do I join the unallocated space in Ubuntu so that Win 8 understands that there is an extra space of 1.36TB??

Comment: What partition table is there? In order to use a drive with more than 2TB, you need a GUID partition table, GPT. If you have an MSDOS partition table, you can only use 'the first two TB', so I suspect that this is the problem. You can check with the command `sudo parted -ls`; It  might be possible to convert the partition table, but it is risky, and you should backup everything, that you cannot afford to lose before you start on that adventure. Another way is to make a fresh installation to a drive with GPT, where you use a copy of the previous `/home` directory in a separate 'home' partition.

Comment: ... You will have to install the program packages [that you installed manually] again, and also re-do global tweaks (for example located in `/etc`], but on the other hand you will get a fresh system, and get rid of 'old junk', that you are no longer using, and that might interfere with some new programs/versions.